# OpenVPN and heartbeat

Tags: openvpn, heartbeat, debian-wheezy

I have several servers connected to OpenVPN and I want to make a simple IP failover with a heartbeat, but I can't figure out how to assign a virtual OpenVPN IP.

Here is my config ha.cf on server1:

```
keepalive       2
deadtime        10
udpport         694
bcast           tun0
mcast           tun0 225.0.0.1 694 1 0
ucast           tun0 10.8.0.22
udp             tun0
logfacility     local0
node            server1
node            server2
```

Is it possible to configure a heartbeat in OpenVPN network?

Comment: What's your underlying platform?  CentOS?  Ubuntu?

Comment: I use debian wheezy

Comment: I'm no debian expert, but all the heartbeat versions I've used recently require some kind of resource manager on the back end; often `crm`.  Do you know what you're using at the back end?

Comment: I have no idea about resource manager, I've just installed heartbeat with apt-get and configured two servers. Here is my config ha.cf on server1:
keepalive 2
deadtime 10
udpport        694
bcast  tun0
mcast tun0 225.0.0.1 694 1 0
ucast tun0 10.8.0.22
#       What interfaces to heartbeat over?
udp     tun0
logfacility     local0
node    server1
node    server2

Comment: I'm doing OpenVPN under HA right now, on CentOS - but it needs a back end to configure the controlled resources.  I'm using crm.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to configure redundant OpenVPN service I usually use built-in support of multiple `--remote` options in client configuration file.

The OpenVPN client then tries to connect to a server in the order of these options. If there is a kind of network problem like disconnection from server a client will try to re-connect to a next server. The options `ping` and `ping-restart` help to detect such conditions if UDP protocol is used for communication.

Comment: I'm not configuring redundant openvpn, I need configure failover of servers in openvpn network